# How to add new line in end of arguments eclipse [editor]

Tags: eclipse, editor

currently my codes i look like this and

```
holder a=new holder(a,s,c,v,b,n,q,w,e,r);
```

i want it to look like this

```
holder a=new holder(a,
                    s,
                    c,
                    v,
                    b,
                    n,
                    q,
                    w,
                    e,
                    r);
```

dose any one knew how can i do this with  auto format ctrl+shift+f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse 4.2

Code format --> Line Wrapping --> Function Calls --> Object Allocation Arguments

Choose "Wrap all elements, Every element in new line"

Answer (score 1):

All options regarding Eclipse's Automated Formatting can be found by going to Window -> Preferences then choosing Java -> Code Style -> Formatter. Click on the Edit... button and change the formatting options as you like.

Although I'm unsure whether the specific configurations of arguments you want is easy to configure. Clicking on the New Lines tab and looking at Array Initializers the configuration you want is unavailable.

It might be hidden somewhere else but I doubt it.